# Cannot resolve method super() error in fragmentmanager Android

Tags: java, android, constructor, super, android-fragment-manager

I am not a Java coder but trying to build an app while trying to learn Java along the way.
I am trying to add 2 fragments one is the login fragment and one is the register fragment but while using super constructor I am facing cannot resolve error.
Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

I get that super is used for accessing the parent class constructor which in my case is not empty.

Following is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager2 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        AuthenticationPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new AuthenticationPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_login());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new fragment_register());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

    public static class AuthenticationPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        public AuthenticationPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentActivity)
        {
            super(fragmentActivity);
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int i)
        {
            return fragmentList.get(i);
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return fragmentList.size();
        }

        void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            fragmentList.add(fragment);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `super()` in a constructor you are trying to call the constructor of the parent class.

In this case the [`FragmentStateAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter) has 3 constructors:

```
FragmentStateAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity)
FragmentStateAdapter(Fragment fragment)
FragmentStateAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Lifecycle lifecycle)
```

In your case you have:

```
public AuthenticationPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentActivity)
```

and `super(FragmentManager);` **doesn't match** any super constructor.

You can use something like:

```
public AuthenticationPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

public AuthenticationPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }
```

Comment: Pardon for the late reply but I solved it using 
"FragmentStateAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Lifecycle lifecycle)" 

and adding a null parameter for lifecycle:

"AuthenticationPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new AuthenticationPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);" 

Gradle succesfully builds but keeps crashing. I guess I cannot provide null to a lifecycle event

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible using `super()` for `fragmentActivity` parameter. You should send a values to `super()` method from higher situated constructor. By the way I can't see a constructor for `MainActivity` class. From which one class you want get a values?